# Passing a method to another method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, lambda

Is it somehow possible to send a function to another function for it to run.
For instance...I want to have an attribute on a field where I can specify a method that will be sent to another method where the method passed in will be run.

Not sure if that makes any sense but here's a small example.

```
[ValidateIf(x=>x.test())]
public string test { get; set; }
```

**Update:**
Basically I want to use DataAnnotations for validation but sometimes depending on the system settings a field may not be mandatory...Do you have any suggestions on the direction I should head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use delegates as properties for attributes. You'd have to specify the method name and then create the delegate using reflection at execution time - which obviously isn't ideal in terms of finding typos at compile time.

It *might* be possible in IL (specifying a `MethodInfo` using an equivalent to `typeof`) but C# doesn't expose any way of doing this :( Maybe one day we'll get the `infoof` operator... quite how it would be exposed, I'm not sure. (It would be good to keep the delegate type information in the attribute.)

Comment: Bassically I want to use DataAnnotations for validation but sometimes depending on the system settings a field may be not mandatory...Do you have any suggestions on the direction I should head?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will meet your specific goal, but in general if you are looking to add data annotations to your language, I recomend you look at Spec#.  This is an extension of the C# language that allows you to add data contracts to your program and appears to accomplish the goal you're looking for.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to add validation to your domain objects, you could take a look at NHibernate Validator.

http://nhibernate.info/doc/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.html